# Bash script: find and replace uppercase character on a string

Tags: string, macos, bash, replace, terminal

Saying we have a string like:

```
doSomething()
```

and we want to obtain:

```
do_something()
```

What is the best way to do this?
I've read [**documentation**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) about *strings manipulation* but I can't find the right command combination..

### update

After @anubhava discussion, I find solution installing gnu-sed:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

And then I can run script in this way:

```
s="doSomethingElse()"; gsed 's/[[:upper:]]/_\L&/g' <<< "$s"
```

**output:** do_something_else()

Comment: I've been trying to use Bash 4 case modifying [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to do this, but have failed so far. (I expect it would take at least two distinct expansions.) I wonder if it's possible to do with just PE and reassignments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `gnu-sed` you can do:

```
s='doSomethingElse()'

sed 's/[[:upper:]]/_\L&/g' <<< "$s"
do_something_else()
```

Or else with `non-gnu-sed (BSD)` pipe with `tr`:

```
sed 's/[[:upper:]]/_&/g' <<< "$s" | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]
do_something_else()
```

Or using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/[[:upper:]]/_\L$&/g' <<< "$s"
do_something_else()
```

Or using `gnu-awk`:

```
awk -v RS=[[:upper:]] -v ORS= '1; RT{printf "_%s", tolower(RT)}' <<< "$s"
do_something_else()
```

Comment: I'm using iTerm under mac (and also awk doesn't work for me)

Comment: `ITerm` is just a terminal. OSX by default doesn't ship with gnu utilities. On my OSX (where I tested both commands) I've installed gnu-sed and gnu-awk using `home brew`.

Comment: ok, but in this case other user have to install "gnu-sed" to correctly run the script

Comment: On OSX `sed` you can use `sed 's/[[:upper:]]/_&/g' <<< "$s" | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash :)

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` 4:

```
$ s="doSomethingElse()"
$ while [[ $s =~ [[:lower:]]([[:upper:]]) ]]; do   
>     s=${s/[[:upper:]]/_${BASH_REMATCH[1],,}}
> done
$ echo "$s"
do_something_else()
```

First, the while loop tries to match a lowercase character immediately followed by an uppercase character, and capturing the matched uppercase character. The parameter expansion replaces the first uppercase character in the string with an underscore and the captured uppercase character (converted to lowercase by the `,,` operator). The processes repeats until no more lower/upper pairs are found.

---

If `bash` allowed capture groups in patterns, something hypothetical like

```
s=${s//([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/${BASH_PATMATCH[1]}_${BASH_PATMATCH[2],,}}
```

could work without a loop. As is, we need the extra step of using regular expression matches one match at a time to capture the letter to be lowercased.